# How to load data into a SQL Server from all CSV files saved into a folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I need to take all CSV files saved into a folder (I don't know the files names because they are automatically generated and they are named after the day and time when they were generated) and save their data into the same SQL Server.

I am able to save data to a SQL Server from a single CSV file if I specify the file name in the SQL script, but I would like SSMS to take all files stored in a folder and load their data in a table on a SQL Server without having to specify the files names.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Look into SSIS packages they do data transfer and this is perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: `OPENROWSET` in serverless SQL pool supports wildcards in the path for this kind of thing. Doesn't look like this exists in on prem yet

Answer (score 0):

My fist thought would be to use SSIS, however, there is another option `xp_dirtree`. You can capture the file names to be processed

**Example**

```
Declare @Table table (Name varchar(500),Depth int,IsFile int)

Insert into @Table
EXEC xp_dirtree  'C:\Working',1,1

Select * From @Table Where IsFile=1
```